# How can I test that a private function was called on a click event?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I am learning jest and I am trying to test my click events. My function that I am trying to test is private within the component.

I have tried using the spyOn() method.

This is the component calling the function

```
<NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggleNavbar} />
```

This is the function

```
    private toggleNavbar = (): void => {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
        });
    }
```

This is the test

```
it('toggleNavbar is called when NavbarToggler is clicked', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<NavBar />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();

    jest.spyOn(instance, 'toggleNavbar');

    wrapper.find(NavbarToggler).simulate('click');

    expect(instance.toggleNavbar).toEqual(true);
});
```

I am currently getting an error on jest.spyOn saying toggleNavbar is not assignable to parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More often than not you shouldn't need to do that as you'd be testing implementation detail of a component - it'd make your test fragile. If your private method sets a state, then the state most likely changes the output of what component renders. You should assert that after it's triggered (via a click for example), the output of render function contains that change.

Assuming you're using `enzyme`

```js
    // expect(wrapper.find(Navbar)).not.toExist(); // enzyme-matchers provides `toExists()`
    wrapper.find(NavbarToggler).simulate('click');
    expect(wrapper.find(Navbar)).toExist(); // enzyme-matchers provides `toExists()`
```

To answer your question - if you're using `enzyme` you can inspect component's state. Another super dirty solution would be `instance.toggleNavbar = jest.fn()`, though as said before, you should never need to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes sense.